# How strong are Jessica and Luke?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones, luke-cage

In Jessica Jones, and the upcoming Luke Cage spin off, how strong are they, objectively? Jessica can obviously be hurt by a gun shot, while Luke can take a power saw to the gut, so they both have different powers, but how big of a difference is it? Is Jessica **Cap** level strong or stronger? Is Luke **Hulk** level impervious?

Both offensive and defensive ratings please. MCU only, comic sources aren't relevant here. Try to avoid/hide any plot spoilers as I haven't finished the first season yet.

Comment: @Pureferret they will have individual show but they can have cameo appearances in each other, Luke even appeared as a supporting character in Jessica Jones.

Comment: @Pureferret  Luke is a crucial part of Jessica Jones' story, but will star in his own show, and will likely have Rand/Iron Fist as a supporting character before Iron Fist stars in his own show, prior to the combined Defenders show.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is Jessica Cap level strong or stronger? Is Luke Hulk level impervious?

Nope.

### As far as the Netflix show goes, there's enough information to confirm that Jessica has these powers:

**Superhuman Strength:** Jessica has strength beyond that of a regular human, especially notable regarding her size. She was able to completely crush an alarm clock with a single hand when she tried to sleep off a hangover, lift a slow moving car and hit a man with enough strength to make him fly across the street.

**Enhanced Speed:** Jessica's overall strength allows her to run at speeds superior to the average human. She was able to catch up to a car fairly easily, and stated she can run a mile in under four minutes.

**Enhanced Durability:** Jessica has durability far beyond that of a regular human, being able to resist multiple beatings with little to no visible injuries. However, she is still vulnerable to gunshots and explosions.

**Regenerative Healing Factor:** Her augmented metabolism heals faster than an ordinary human being. She is capable of completely healing minor scratches and injuries in mere hours, and major injuries like broken ribs in just a single day. It may also allow her to not be affected by the harmful and long term affects of alcohol, leaving her only to experience intoxication and hangover while not experiencing any signs of toxicity.

**Flight:** Jessica is able to fly, though she has never mastered this ability. She can propel herself off a surface and through the air at various speeds and altitudes, but she sometimes gets injured while landing. Jones refers to this as "guided falling."

### Moving on to Luke:

**Superhuman Strength:** During a fight in his bar where different opponents attacked him, Cage effortlessly tosses them from him and overpowers them. He is able to punch through solid walls and dent the auto body of motor vehicles with these punches. He is able to match Jessica Jones in strength, and push her back during a fight.

**Superhuman Durability:** Cage has extremely durable skin. He demonstrated it to Jones using a circular saw against his own stomach, and he survived both being stabbed in the neck and being shot with a shotgun. A doctor's drill began to smoke when drilling against his skin. Cage's skin is also fire resistant as demonstrated by him being able to withstand a point blank explosion and not feel a thing when Cage emerged from a building on fire. Nevertheless, Cage is susceptible to internal injuries and treating such injuries are complicated by the fact that Cage's extremely durable skin makes invasive surgery practically impossible. Cage could be at risk of dying from untreated internal fatal conditions, such as hydrocephalus.

Comment: "He demonstrated it to Jones using a circular saw against his own stomach," - I am yet to finish all episodes yet but does Jessica Jones appear in later episodes of Luke Cage? IMDB hasn't listed her character in the show's list. Or this happened in Jessica Jones episodes?